# Ugly bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement the bootstrap-datepicker.js plugin. (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I have the .js and .css files in place, but I'm getting this ugly standard jquery datepicker in chinese:

[image]

```
$('#test').datepicker({ });
```

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" class="sm-form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-JJJJ" autocomplete="off">    

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').datepicker({
         onSelect: function(d,i){
              if(d !== i.lastVal){
                  $(this).change();
              }
         }
    });
    $('#test').change(function(){
         console.log('Test');
    });
});
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Please link the specific bootstrap plugin you are using as there are a plethora of plugins.

Comment: This is the plugin: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Try setting   **language: 'en'**  inside your datepicker method.

Comment: `    $('#test').datepicker({
         language: 'en',
    });` is still outputting a chinese calendar

Comment: Can you provide your code in a snippet?

Comment: I editted my post with my code

Comment: Make sure still don't have other datepicker JS in your code, like [Jquery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) Its looking like bit same.

Comment: Are you using jquery ui in your page? check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137392/datepicker-is-always-displayed-in-simplified-chinese

Comment: I think its jQuery-Ui plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an conflict between `JQueryUI` and `Bootstrap` for `datepicker` check [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277563/jquery-ui-datepicker-conflict-with-bootstrap-datepicker)

```
$.fn.datepicker.noConflict = function(){
 $.fn.datepicker = old;
  return this;
  };
```

or you can use `JQuery-UI`

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#test" ).datepicker({
    language: 'zh-TW'
    });     
  });
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
   <script src="i18n/datepicker-zh-TW.js"></script>
<body>
 
<p>Date:<input type="text" id="test" name="test" class="sm-form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-JJJJ" autocomplete="off">    

 </body>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it was a conflict between the two. It was already installed and called for in the template in a JS file. Just found out. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin supports `i18n` for the month and `weekday` names and the `weekStart` option.

The default is English (en); other available translations are available in the **js/locales/** directory, simply include your desired locale after the plugin.

To add more languages, simply add a key to $.fn.datepicker.dates, before calling .datepicker(). Example:

```
$.fn.datepicker.dates['en'] = {
days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
today: "Today",
clear: "Clear",
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
titleFormat: "MM yyyy", /* Leverages same syntax as 'format' */
weekStart: 0
```

};

Right-to-left languages may also include rtl: true to make the calendar display appropriately.

If your browser (or those of your users) is displaying characters wrong, chances are the browser is loading the javascript file with a non-unicode encoding. Simply add charset="UTF-8" to your script tag:

`<script src="bootstrap-datepicker.XX.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'en'
   });
```